# Is this script safe enough from sql injections?

Tags: php

Is  this script safe enough from sql injections? Or is it possible to improve it more  efficiently?
Because i am going to  use it in public  and don't know about this line
 "mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['user_id']);" Perhaps its possible to improve  it more.

```
<?
    $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);

    if ($id == 1)
      {
        $userinfo['user_id'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['user_id']);
        $info = $db->fetchArray("SELECT points FROM ". PREFIX ."list WHERE user_id = '{$userinfo['user_id']}'");

        if (!empty($info))
        {
            $user_rank = UserRank($userinfo['user_id']);

            header('Content-type: image/png');
            $points = $info['server_points'];
            $line = "empty";
            $nr = "Number";
            $font = 3;
            $font2 = 2;
            $width = ImageFontWidth($font)* strlen($nr) ;
            $width2 = ImageFontWidth($font)* strlen($points);
            $height = ImageFontHeight($font);

            $im = ImageCreateFrompng(SYS_USER .'/banner.png');
            $points_text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 225, 100, 112);
            $nr_text_color = imagecolorallocate ($im, 217, 153, 101);
            $line_color = imagecolorallocate ($im, 100, 123, 134);
            imagestring ($im, $font, 40, 18, $points, $points_text_color);
            imagestring ($im, $font2, 40, 11, $line, $line_color);
            imagestring ($im, $font2, 40, 4, $nr, $nr_text_color);
            imagestring ($im, $font, 60, 4, $user_rank, $nr_text_color);

            imagepng($im); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is PREFIX? Where does it come from?

Comment: Well, if you used is_numeric() you could be sure only number will get through

Comment: Belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: also, how can $id == 1? mysql_real_escape_string returns a string or false...

Answer (score 2):

for `$id` use function `is_numeric()`:

```
if(is_numeric($id)) { // if id not numeric -> false else -> true
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would seriously consider using bind_param when interacting with sql variables. Your code is such a good example of strings coming from many different places which could possibly have been jeopardized. bind_param enforces that there are no injection attacks in the strings you pass in. If for anything, itll at least give you enough peace of mind not to worry so much to ask this question.

Example:

```
$name = "Robert ') DROP TABLE Students;"; //see: http://xkcd.com/327/
$conn = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) or 
    die('There was a problem connecting to the database.');
$query = "SELECT id FROM Users WHERE name=?";
if ($stmt = $conn->prepare($query)) {
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $name);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($result);
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        echo $result;
    }
    $stmt->close();
}
```